# Extract a list of profileId's using jsonpath

Tags: groovy, jsonpath

I have the following JSON object `r2`,

```
[
   {
      "reserva_id":"200",
      "estancias":[
         {
            "reserva_estancia":"266",
            "huespedes":[
               {
                  "reserva_huesped":"272",
                  "reserva_estancia":"266",
                  "numero_huesped":"1",
                  "huesped":"123",
                  "huesped_nombre":"dos dos, dos",
                  "rfid":null
               },
               {
                  "reserva_huesped":"276",
                  "reserva_estancia":"266",
                  "numero_huesped":"2",
                  "huesped":"183",
                  "huesped_nombre":"MUESTRA MUESTRA, CARMEN",
                  "rfid":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "reserva_id":"201",
      "estancias":[
         {
            "huespedes":[
               {
                  "reserva_huesped":"273",
                  "reserva_estancia":"267",
                  "numero_huesped":"1",
                  "huesped":"148",
                  "huesped_nombre":"MUESTRA MUESTRA, CARMEN",
                  "rfid":null
               },
               {
                  "reserva_huesped":"277",
                  "reserva_estancia":"267",
                  "numero_huesped":"2",
                  "huesped":"187",
                  "huesped_nombre":"TEST TEST, TESTCIVITFUN",
                  "rfid":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am trying to get the first `huesped` for each reservation, and for that I am using the following script, to create a list called profiles and store profileId's:

```
def profiles = jsonpath(r2,'$..[:].estancias[:].huespedes[0].huesped')
```

The output should be the following:

```
[
  "123",
  "148"
]
```

However, when I print `profiles.text` I get all the content of the `estancias` object, instead of just the `huesped` number.

Comment: Where do you use this? JMeter, SoapUI? I cannot add further instructions since I do not know your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Jayway's JSONPath like this I get the desired oputput:

```
$..[*].estancias[*].huespedes[0].huesped
```

You can try the path expression with your JSON [here online](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).